Printing legal entries in bibliography using biblatex-chicago
I was hoping someone could help me with a question regarding the behaviour of legal citations in biblatex-chicago as it relates to printing such references in a bibliography section (or a special list for legal, legislation and jurisdiction bib entries).
As far as I understand, following closely to the Bluebook guidelines, legal citations are not included in a reference list by default.
From reading the documentation of biblatex-chicago, I understand that using the legalnotes=false option could change this default decision.
However, nothing happens.
My expected result is to have some sort of table of authorities apart from the general reference list, but in any case the \printbibliography command has no output for legal references.
